# Does $\frac{a_i}{b_i} \geq \frac{c_i}{d_i}$ implies $\frac{\sum_i a_i}{\sum_i b_i} \geq \frac{\sum_i c_i}{\sum_i d_i}$

Tags: inequality

Suppose $a_i$, $b_i$, $c_i$, and $d_i$ are all positive real numbers, and that for any $i$,
$$\frac{a_i}{b_i} \geq \frac{c_i}{d_i}.$$
Does this implies that
$$\frac{\sum_i a_i}{\sum_i  b_i} \geq \frac{\sum_i  c_i}{\sum_i  d_i}?$$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @wbitting95 numbers should be positive reals.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not.

Suppose that $a_1$, $a_2$, $b_1$, $b_2$, $c_1$, $c_2$, $d_1$, $d_2$ are $4$, $8$, $1$, $4$, $12$, $1$, $4$, $1$, respectively. They are all positive real numbers.

$$
\begin{aligned}
& \frac{a_1}{b_1} = \frac{4}{1} = 4 > 3 = \frac{12}{4} = \frac{c_1}{d_1}, \\
& \frac{a_2}{b_2} = \frac{8}{4} = 2 > 1 = \frac{1}{1} = \frac{c_2}{d_2}, \\
\end{aligned}
$$
but
$$
\frac{a_1 + a_2}{b_1 + b_2} = \frac{4+8}{1+4} = \frac{12}{5} < \frac{13}{5} = \frac{12+1}{4+1} = \frac{c_1 + c_2}{d_1 + d_2}.
$$

Comment: This question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards).  Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.

Comment: @AnneBauval I did not notice it. Thanks for pointing it out.